# Problemas de ejecución de programa en C

Tags: visual, codeblocks, studio

tengo el siguiente código escrito en C y he probado a compilarlo y ejecutarlo en 4 programas  diferentes:

1. En https://www.onlinegdb.com y en Codeblocks me compila el código con un array de tamaño variable que dependerá de "cantidad_numeros" sin problema y me indica qué números he introducido de forma correcta y qué números he fallado. Este todo OK.
2. En Visual Studio Code me compila el programa con un array de tamaño variable pero no me muestra los números que he fallado o acertado, solo me hace una lista y me dice que los he acertado todos. He probado a cambiar la variable del "if(numeros_acertados[i])" a "if (acierto == true)" y tampoco funciona. Por eso está marcado como comentario con "//".
3. En Visual Studio no me compila el programa si el array tiene un tamaño variable, solo lo compila si indico que los array son "numeros [10]", "numeros acertados [10] y así; pero no me indica qué números he acertado y qué números he fallado.

A ver si alguien sabe por qué, yo entiendo que es el compilador pero entonces no entiendo por qué ejecuta cosas diferentes o qué puedo hacer para que ejecute lo mismo en todos los programas (aunque sea con un array de 10 posiciones).

El código es:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(void) {
  int limite_inf = 5, limite_sup = 10;
  srand(time(NULL));

  int cantidad_numeros = (rand() % (limite_sup - limite_inf + 1)) + limite_inf;
 

  int i;

  int numeros[cantidad_numeros], numeros_introducidos[cantidad_numeros];
  int numeros_acertados[cantidad_numeros], numero_acertado = 0;
  float porcentaje_aciertos;
  //bool acierto;

  printf("Se han generado %d numeros aleatorios\n", cantidad_numeros);
  printf("Es tu turno jugador. Vas a llenar tu el array.\nRecuerda que has de usar numeros del 1 al 4!\n");

  for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
    numeros[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    // printf("%d\n", numeros[i]);
   }

   i = 0;
   //acierto = true;

   while (i < cantidad_numeros) {
    printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &numeros_introducidos[i]); 
    
    if (numeros_introducidos[i] < 1 || numeros_introducidos[i] > 4) {
        printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &numeros_introducidos[i]);
    } else {
        if (numeros_introducidos[i] == numeros[i]) {
            numero_acertado++;
            numeros_acertados[i] = 1;
        }
        //else {
           //acierto = false;
        //}
        i++;
    }
}

porcentaje_aciertos = (float)numero_acertado * 100 / cantidad_numeros;
printf("Has acertado %d numeros de %d\n", numero_acertado, cantidad_numeros);
printf("Lo que representa un %.2f %% \n", porcentaje_aciertos);

printf("Has acertado los siguientes\n");

for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
    if (numeros_acertados[i]) {
        printf("Posicion %i has indicado %d y habia un %d\n", i + 1, numeros_introducidos[i], numeros[i]);
    }
}

printf ("Has fallado los siguientes\n");

for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
    if (!numeros_acertados[i]) {
        printf("Posicion %i has indicado %d y habia un %d\n", i + 1, numeros_introducidos[i], numeros[i]);
    }
}

printf("El resumen de las introducciones es el siguiente:\n");

for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
    if (numeros_acertados[i]) {
        printf("Posicion %i has indicado un %d y habia un %d, por tanto has acertado!\n", i + 1, numeros_introducidos[i], numeros[i]);
        
    } else {
        printf("Posicion %i has indicado un %d y habia un %d, por tanto has fallado!\n", i + 1, numeros_introducidos[i], numeros[i]);
        
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general en C es complicado trabajar con arreglos de largo variable. En consecuencia, lo que se hace usualmente es usar `malloc()` y `free()` para pedir y liberar memoria dinámica.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
  int limite_inf = 5, limite_sup = 10;
  srand(time(NULL));

  int cantidad_numeros = (rand() % (limite_sup - limite_inf + 1)) + limite_inf;

  int i;

  int *numeros = malloc(cantidad_numeros * sizeof(int));
  int *numeros_introducidos = malloc(cantidad_numeros * sizeof(int));
  int *numeros_acertados = malloc(cantidad_numeros * sizeof(int));
  int numero_acertado = 0;
  float porcentaje_aciertos;
  //bool acierto;

  printf("Se han generado %d numeros aleatorios\n", cantidad_numeros);
  printf("Es tu turno jugador. Vas a llenar tu el array.\nRecuerda que has de usar numeros del 1 al 4!\n");

  for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
    numeros[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    // printf("%d\n", numeros[i]);
  }

  i = 0;
  //acierto = true;

  while (i < cantidad_numeros) {
    printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &numeros_introducidos[i]);

    if (numeros_introducidos[i] < 1 || numeros_introducidos[i] > 4) {
      printf("Introduce el entero del 1 al 4 numero %i\n", i + 1);
      scanf("%d", &numeros_introducidos[i]);
    } else {
      if (numeros_introducidos[i] == numeros[i]) {
        numero_acertado++;
        numeros_acertados[i] = 1;
      }
      //else {
      //acierto = false;
      //}
      i++;
    }
  }

  porcentaje_aciertos = (float) numero_acertado * 100 / cantidad_numeros;
  printf("Has acertado %d numeros de %d\n", numero_acertado, cantidad_numeros);
  printf("Lo que representa un %.2f %% \n", porcentaje_aciertos);

  printf("Los numeros generados eran\n");   // Nuevo
  for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {  // Nuevo
    printf("%d  ", numeros[i]);             // Nuevo
  }                                         // Nuevo
  printf("\n");                             // Nuevo

  printf("Los numeros introducidos eran\n");   // Nuevo
  for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {     // Nuevo
    printf("%d  ", numeros_introducidos[i]);   // Nuevo
  }                                            // Nuevo
  printf("\n");                                // Nuevo

  printf("Has acertado los siguientes\n");

  for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
    if (numeros_acertados[i]) {
      printf("Posicion %i has indicado %d y habia un %d\n", i + 1, numeros_introducidos[i], numeros[i]);
    }
  }

  printf("Has fallado los siguientes\n");

  for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
    if (!numeros_acertados[i]) {
      printf("Posicion %i has indicado %d y habia un %d\n", i + 1, numeros_introducidos[i], numeros[i]);
    }
  }

  printf("El resumen de las introducciones es el siguiente:\n");

  for (i = 0; i < cantidad_numeros; i++) {
    if (numeros_acertados[i]) {
      printf("Posicion %i has indicado un %d y habia un %d, por tanto has acertado!\n", i + 1, numeros_introducidos[i], numeros[i]);

    } else {
      printf("Posicion %i has indicado un %d y habia un %d, por tanto has fallado!\n", i + 1, numeros_introducidos[i], numeros[i]);

    }
  }

  free(numeros);
  free(numeros_introducidos);
  free(numeros_acertados);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he podido ejecutar el código aunque en Visual Studio todavía me sale mal el final en los otros programas ya ejecuta bien todo lo que pido :)